# Connecting multiple access points

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm working on a big project.
We want to create a wireless network throughout the building with 15 floors.
My idea is that we should set up one unified wireless access point at least in each floor...in case of signal 
attenuate, we use Access point extender/repeater.
I selected DWL-6600AP from among D-Link industrial access points.
I want to implement a single wireless LAN throughout the building.

Is it possible to combines multiple DWL-6600 access points to achieving just a single WLAN? 
Can a wireless switch controller do this task?
Can these Access Points interfere with each other? What is the solution?
I read D-Link website's learning materials, but I am still confused.

My other question is around the connecting these APs to Wireless Switch Controller -
Is it possible to use power line for connecting DWL-6600 to Wireless Switch Controller 
device?

---

**My main goal is that clients with portable devices such as laptops should be easily connected to the network to share & have communication without any more manual configuration as they are already connected to a single network.**

Comment: thank you, i found the answer, i have spent a lot of time to finding a solution to visualizing to how installing & maintaining (specifically securing wireless networks). the explanation  is published inside a book written by Cisco. it's name is Implementing Cisco Unified Wireless Networking Essentials...turn over the ebook into 29 page. all necessary information for infrastructural wireless networking are described.

Comment: to making secure your WLAN, just search on google this phrase" Wireless Network  intrusion prevention"

Answer (score 1):

You might have better result with multiple APs on non-overlapping channels sharing the same SSID (i.e. an [ESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN#Extended_service_set)). The MAC protocol of 802.11 cannot cope very well if you have a large number of stations accessing the same [BSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN#Basic_service_set) (i.e. single master AP) via repeaters.

Many Wi-Fi clients handle "romaing" between BSSes very well. The crucial point is that the network must handle the switch from one AP to another seamlessly. The base line is that the client's IP must not change and on going connections must not be interrupted at the protocol level. The is easy to achieve (just make all the APs connect to the same LAN and share the same DHCP and NAT server/router). However, to improve the romaing exprience you may need smarter switches that are aware of the location of the clients.

As of your second question, most people would just use PoE. Alternatively you can use a [powerline network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication#Home_networking_.28LAN.29), but the bandwidth is not very good.

Good reference: http://wirelessinfo-r-us.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/basic-service-set-bss-vs-extended.html

Comment: could you please explain which switch is appropriated for this purpose? and how about Wireless switch controller? can it be helpful? we have about 200 clients in every floor.

Comment: Yeah, it will probably be branded as a wireless controller or something like that. Could you give the actual brand and model name of the "Wireless switch controller" you're refering to though?

Comment: http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/wireless/unified-wireless              i think DWS-4026 is fine. take a look to it.

Comment: i am not sure a wireless controller can combine APs...what do you think ?

Comment: The mobile station (client) is responsible for detecting and reassociating with APs with a better signal strength. The APs or switches have no control over it. They'll just have to ensure packets are switched to the new AP once the client reassociates. Since most APs buffer frames, a few could be lost when the client associates with another AP in the same network. A romaing-aware switch should then send the frame to the new AP. The documentation of the device you suggested has a section called "Seamless Mobility" which seems to suggest it has such capability.

Comment: sorry..i am confused...At this time tell me which solution is better? using Wireless controller or not ? do you have any experiance ?

Comment: I think your wireless controller solution is adequate, but you shoudn't use any repeaters. Just use individual APs controlled by the same controller and you should be fine. You should always contact D-Link and verify your plan with them to make sure the equipment can support that.

Comment: can you explain more why i should not set up repeaters?

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the Ubiquity product 'Unifi'

http://www.ubnt.com/unifi

Comment: Cool, unless the op has already bought someone else's hardware (like the D-Links).

Comment: Isn't this always the case with StackExchange?  Just post an answer and help the masses :)